# How to change time to just day/month with twitter json result?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am getting this result when trying to access my twitter feed with PHP:

```
Sat Apr 07 07:29:11 +0000 2012
```

How can I change it so it's only "`Apr 07`"?

Code I am using:

```
   $tweets = getTweets("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/justinbieber.json?count=3");
      foreach($tweets as $tweet) {

        $time = $tweet->created_at;


}
```

Comment: Sorry... I don't know how I can be more descriptive about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to  convert it to a timestamp and then format it using [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) or `date()`.

```
echo strftime('%h %d', strtotime('Sat Apr 07 07:29:11 +0000 2012'));
# Apr 07
```

So in your case:

```
$time = strftime('%h %d', strtotime($tweet->created_at));
```

However, calling a variable containing month and day "time" is a really bad idea. It's a date after all.

Comment: Well, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: No, `strtotime()` is the best way to convert a time string into a timestamp. Just don't call the variable where you store the formatted *date* `$time` but e.g. `$date` ;)